# Javascript Move .active class within array objects

Tags: javascript, html, dom

If I have a div with four images in it

```
<div id='imgs' class='sectionImage'>
    <img id='imgj1' imgn='1' class='carouselImage carouselActive' src='img/image1.jpg'/>
    <img id='imgj2' imgn='2' class='carouselImage' src='img/image2.jpg'/>
    <img id='imgj3' imgn='3' class='carouselImage' src='img/image3.jpg'/>
    <img  id='imgj4' imgn='4'class='carouselImage' src='img/image4.jpg'/>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

How would I set up an array and function to scroll through the four images in the array by moving the active class to the next image and keep cycling? Javascript only please...no library

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Working on an answer for you now. What browser support do you need?

Comment: I have been testing in chrome and safari so far.

Answer (score 1):

Define two functions: one for going to the next and one to the previous:

```
    function gotoNext() {
        var active = document.querySelector(".carouselImage.carouselActive");  //select active image
        if (active == null) { //if no active image select the first
            document.querySelector(".carouselImage[imgn='1']").className += " carouselActive";
        } else {
            active.className = "carouselImage";
            var curId = active.getAttribute("imgn"); //imgn of selected image
            var next = document.querySelector(".carouselImage[imgn='" + (++curId) + "']"); //next image. if there is no next image select the first
            if (next == null) document.querySelector(".carouselImage[imgn='1']").className += " carouselActive";
            else next.className += " carouselActive";
        }
    }

function gotoPrev() {
    var active = document.querySelector(".carouselImage.carouselActive");  //select active image
    if (active == null) { //if no active image select the first
        document.querySelector(".carouselImage[imgn='1']").className += " carouselActive";
    } else {
        active.className = "carouselImage";
        var curId = active.getAttribute("imgn"); //imgn of selected image
        var prev = document.querySelector(".carouselImage[imgn='" + (--curId) + "']"); //prev image. if there is no prev image select the last
        if (prev == null) document.querySelector(".carouselImage[imgn='4']").className += " carouselActive";
        else prev.className += " carouselActive";
    }
}
```

Note: It would be better to replace className = ... with functions that can remove or add a class. For example jquery has removeClass("className") and addClass("className"). There are also implementations whithout jquery.